# Cron Task Error ([Errno 13] Permission denied)

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run my python script using cron specifically, since that is one requirement for our project. This is the code:

```
* * * * * /mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe "/mnt/c/Users/username/folder/trial.py" > "/mnt/c/Users/username/folder/testfile.log" 2> "/mnt/c/Users/username/folder/testfile_err.log"
```

When I try to check the error logs, it keeps showing me this error:

```
python.exe: can't open file '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\mnt\\c\\Users\\username\\folder\\testing.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've tried adjusting the changing the moderator access using CHMOD, but the error is still showing. Any ideas on what should I do to fix and finally run my cron job?

Thanks!